# WooCommerce header-shop.php - как вывести свой header на странице корзины

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Есть сайт http://rezultatnalitso.sparkmedia.pro/shop - тут в мобильной версии грузится свой hedear из header-shop.php.

А тут http://rezultatnalitso.sparkmedia.pro/cart тоже в мобильной версии  загружается header из header.php.

**Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы и на странице http://rezultatnalitso.sparkmedia.pro/cart загружался свой header из header-shop.php.**

Знаю про `get_header('shop')`, только не пойму куда его вставить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Страница cart - это обычная страница сайта, на которой размещён шорткод `[woocommerce_cart]`. Поэтому в самое начало вашего файла header.php можно добавить проверку, что мы находимся на странице корзины, и вывести соответствующий header:

```
if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) && is_cart() ) {
    get_header('shop');
} else {
    // текущий код header.php
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Так же проделал и c footer-ом